# Failed to resolve: com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.17-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android

Whenever I'm trying to include `worker8/TourGuide` library in my gradle file it is throwing me this error:

> "Failed to resolve: com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.17-SNAPSHOT"

I tried to clean the project and tried to rebuild as well but nothing worked for me. Please provide your help. Thanks in advance.

**app gradle file**

```
android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.example.abdulrehman.myapplication"
                    minSdkVersion 15
                    targetSdkVersion 26
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
                implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            //    compile ('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.13-SNAPSHOT@aar'){
            //        transitive=true
            //    }
                compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
                testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
                androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
                androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
            }
```

**Project gradle file**

```
buildscript {

                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                    google()
                    mavenCentral()
                    maven(){
                        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
                    }
                }
                dependencies {
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
                    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
                }
            }

            allprojects {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                    google()
                }
            }
            task clean(type: Delete) {
                delete rootProject.buildDir
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

dont place third party url in buildscript. place in allprojects.

```
   buildscript {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                }
                dependencies {
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
                    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
                }
            }

            allprojects {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                    google()
                    mavenCentral()
                    maven(){
                            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
                        }
                }
            }
            task clean(type: Delete) {
                delete rootProject.buildDir
            }
```